# How to capture bitmap for animating view?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-bitmap

In my layout I am using a WebView in which I am loading a url, which has a map & some animating objects. I want to capture the bitmap of the layout.
For that I am using following method.

```
Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
```

I also tried other method for capturing bitmap.

```
public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

But after capturing the bitmap I get everything except animating objects. I also tried with static map as well where the objects are not moving but still I get the same result. But when I take the screenshot from device (by pressing Vol- & Power) then it captures everything.

I am really not sure what is the issue.

First image is the WebView where it loads the url with map, pins & path.

[image: This is how the WebView originally looks like]

Second is what it captured using methods mentioned above.

[image: And this is the captured bitmap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do is to set the `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in the Manifest file for my Activity.